# Concatenate two dataframe with condition (coordinates and year corresponding)

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, conditional-statements

i have a problem trying to concatenate under certain condition two dataframes.
I looked different post but i found no solutions that helped me.

Here is my data :

```
Dataframe 1 :

"year"     "var"          "x"                 "y"               "info"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4878686.57157449","5393968.15997648","0.386875003576279"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4896433.83572102","5398120.2484886","0.373374998569489"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4900572.93504345","5370687.20427196","0.394125014543533"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4902934.77310431","5361773.82267221","0.271333336830139"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4763325.11415408","5286260.42907455","0.341958343982697"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4659782.7218849","5251960.76092113","0.407333344221115"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4672416.53746615","5253639.4841048","0.443416655063629"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4688194.71187035","5255824.40292703","0.334916681051254"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4697653.82879809","5257181.46577816","0.367166668176651"

Dataframe 2 :

"year"         "x"             "y"             "species"
 "2014" "4001758.3924046" "3138415.9463486"     "Sus scrofa"
 "2016" "3990684.89200331" "3088575.79671371" "Capreolus capreolus"
 "2014" "4002641.44272945" "3078682.12799716" "Capreolus capreolus"
 "2014" "3946723.09681777" "3153792.59524072" "Capreolus capreolus"
 "2014" "3975356.46700669" "2974349.6604129" "Cervus elaphus"
 "2014" "4001283.9265329" "3137527.57584417" "Capreolus capreolus"
 "2014" "3946723.09681777" "3153792.59524072" "Capreolus capreolus"
 "2014" "3946723.09681777" "3153792.59524072" "Capreolus capreolus"
 "2017" "4000195.01511827" "3103181.07855945" "Capreolus capreolus"
```

The first `dataframe` contains way more `data` than the second one.
What i want to do is : 
`concatenate` the two `dataframes` and keep only the `row` from the first `dataframe` that appears in the second `dataframe`.

I tried different methods: `select and filter, merge, cbind, "by hand" with for loops`, but i can't manage to obtain anything that work.

I also spend a lot of time looking for a solution online, but, or i'm too dumb to see how i could use one solution for my problem, or nobody have the same problem, i don't know, or i didn't make enough research.

If you have any clue of how i could do this, i know it can be very simple.

```
Datafrale 1 :

"1992","mean_ndvi","4688194.71187035","5255824.40292703","0.334916681051254"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4697653.82879809","5257181.46577816","0.367166668176651"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4657938.8843526","5242452.09422199","0.43491667509079"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4661111.26475011","5242863.65256642","0.523041665554047"
"1992","mean_ndvi","4692800.91855509","5247191.53424558","0.405791670084"

Dataframe 2 :

"2014" "4001758.3924046" "3138415.9463486" "Sus scrofa"
"2016" "3990684.89200331" "3088575.79671371" "Capreolus capreolus"
"1992" "4657938.8843526" "5242452.09422199" "Capreolus capreolus"
"2017" "4000167.53545378" "3103446.42513062" "Sus scrofa"
"1992" "4688194.71187035" "5255824.40292703 "Capreolus capreolus"

Result : 

"1992" "4657938.8843526" "5242452.09422199" "Capreolus capreolus""0.43491667509079"
"1992" "4688194.71187035" "5255824.40292703 "Capreolus capreolus" "0.334916681051254"
```

Here is the result for dput (the first 10 rows) :

```
First dataframe (with a lot of data)
structure(list(x = c(4878686.57157449, 4896433.83572102, 4900572.93504345, 
4902934.77310431, 4763325.11415408, 4659782.7218849, 4672416.53746615, 
4688194.71187035, 4697653.82879809, 4657938.8843526), y =     c(5393968.15997648, 
5398120.2484886, 5370687.20427196, 5361773.82267221, 5286260.42907455, 
5251960.76092113, 5253639.4841048, 5255824.40292703, 5257181.46577816, 
5242452.09422199), year = c(1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 
1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L), info = c(0.396166652441025, 
0.373374998569489, 0.394125014543533, 0.28979167342186, 0.344375014305115, 
0.414458334445953, 0.416541665792465, 0.342583328485489, 0.378208339214325, 
0.440750002861023)), .Names = c("x", "y", "year", "info"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

It returns me the whole data frame for the other dataframe, i don't understand why but i can't put it the result it doesn't make any sense

Comment: What do you mean by `keep only the row from the first dataframe`?

Comment: Can you provide sample data with **desired outcome**? As it stands there is no overlap between your two data frames.

Comment: Yes sorry , what i meant was "keep only the row from the row with the coordinates that only appears in the second dataframe, i'll put an example below

Comment: Here, i just edited my post, sorry

Comment: Take a look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618.

Comment: I tried inner, left and right join, i tried intersect too, but i can't make it work, everytime i tried, i had an error on the row, or on the names, or on the type of the data i used (dataframe, vector, etc), and so on

Comment: @Parfait I tried this many times, but the result it give me is completely empty, just no data, 0 row

Comment: @Parfait I just tried your second solution, exactly the same problem !

Comment: Please post the `dput(df_name)` return and past into body of your post as what you post is NOT the same as actual. We know how to use that gobbledygook output.

Comment: I'm sorry @Parfait , what is dput(df_name)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Get fancy data
set.seed(666)

df1 <- iris[sample(x = 1:10, size = 6, replace = FALSE),]
df2 <- iris[sample(x = 1:10, size = 6, replace = FALSE),]

# Get common rows
index <- match(apply(df1, 1, paste, collapse = "-"), 
               apply(df2, 1, paste, collapse = "-"))
index <- index[!is.na(index)]

df3 <- df2[index,]
```

As you can see, df3 will be a data.frame with only common rows.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i tried it on my 24 dataframe, and same problem, it return 0 elements. I'll take a look at the content of my data, because it seems like it never have the same value, i don't see another explanation

Comment: It would be usefull if you share with us some of your (problematic) data frames.

Comment: I'd like to, but how can i share with you without my data being spread on the web ? The files i use are pretty big!

Comment: Not your whole data, just a few significative rows and columns (10x5 maybe?). Use `dput` function.

Comment: Well, do you know how i can use the dput function to give me only the 10 first row ?

Comment: `dput(iris[1:10,])`